# Como extrair somente valores diferentes de um array?

Tags: php, array, web-service

Eu estou extraindo de um `array` nome de cidades. Quero extrair cidades com nomes diferentes. No caso atual, o meu script retorna diversos nomes de cidades iguais. Quero recuperar somente uma vez cada nome de cidade.

O resultado é esse:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [Codigo] => 2
            [Cidade] => Porto Alegre
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Codigo] => 3
            [Cidade] => Porto Alegre
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Codigo] => 4
            [Cidade] => Porto Alegre
        )
    ...
```

O script que está sendo usado é este:

```
$cidades = new Imoveis;
$city = $cidades->get_cidades($cidades->key, $cidades->tipo, $cidades->param);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($city);
```

Esse script me retorna **imóveis** de um `Webservice`, então o lance seria retornar somente 1 imóvel de cada cidade ou agrupar imóveis por `cidade`.

Comment: O código faz diferença para você? é código do que?

Comment: Eu estou desenvolvendo um site a partir de um webservice e queria extrair as cidades para colocar num dropdowm de busca ... http://new.pier36imoveis.com.br/busca

Answer (score 5):

Use [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) combiando com [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) para extrair apenas o valores não repetidos da chave `Cidade`.

`array_column()` está disponível do php5.5 para frente caso esteja usando uma versão anterior, pode usar [essa função](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php) para obter o mesmo resultado.

```
<?php

$arr = array(
            array('codigo' => 1, 'cidade' => 'Porto Alegre'),
            array('codigo' => 3, 'cidade' => 'Porto Alegre'),
            array('codigo' => 8, 'cidade' => 'São Paulo'),
            array('codigo' => 9, 'cidade' => 'Rio de Janeiro'),
            array('codigo' => 10, 'cidade' => 'Rio de Janeiro'),
            array('codigo' => 5, 'cidade' => 'Porto Alegre'));


$arr = array_unique(array_column($arr, 'cidade'));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Porto Alegre
    [2] => São Paulo
    [3] => Rio de Janeiro
)
```

[**Exemplo - phpfiddle**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/p8pv-yqb5)